# Show that for $f$ analytic in $B(0,2)$, $\max_{|z|=1}|\frac{1}{z}-f(z)|\ge 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:B(0,2)\to \Bbb C$ be an analytic function. Show that $$\max_{|z|=1}\left|\frac{1}{z}-f(z)\right|\ge 1.$$

I tried to write $f(z)$ as power series since it is analytic, it doesn't seem work. I also tried to use maximum modulus principle, it also did not work.

Could anyone kindly help? I am really struggling with this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862998/a-question-about-maximum-principle-in-complex-analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try integrating $1/z-f(z)$ around the unit circle.

Comment: I get $2\pi i-\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=2\pi i -i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{it}f(e^{it})dt$, I am really confused what to do next. Could you help give some hint about what to do next? Thanks!

Comment: Well, $f(z)$ is analytic on the entire unit disk.  What does that tell you about $\int_\gamma f(z)dz$?